# Spectral sequence from resolution

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

I am watching Scholze's masterclass on Condensed Mathematics and I don't understand or can find any references on something he said.

You have a resolution

$$ \dots \to \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{R}^2] \to \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{R}] \to \mathbb{R} \to 0$$

Scholze refers to the spectral sequence arising from this complex to later talk about sheaf cohomology, but I am not sure what he means. Maybe he uses the filtration induced by truncation?

A similar thing is referenced in his [notes](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf) (see Corollary  4.8), where he has a resolution and in that case he mentions this is obtained by applying RHom, but I am not sure how you get a spectral sequence then either.